# Is the intersection of distinct conjugations of Sylow subgroups trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group.

Let $P,Q$ be Sylow p-subgroups of $G$.

If $P\neq Q$, how do i prove that $P\cap Q=1$?

I was trying to use the inner automorphism to prove this, but i couldn't prove this..

Please help!

Comment: This can't be true in general; for example, if $G$ has a nontrivial center then it has a nontrivial central element of order $p$ for some prime $p$, so this nontrivial central element must lie in one and hence every Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general: look at the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_3 \times S_3$. The Sylow $2$-subgroups $P=\langle (1 2)\rangle \times \langle(2 3)\rangle$ and $Q=\langle (12)\rangle \times \langle(1 2)\rangle$ have the subgroup $\langle (1 2)\rangle \times \langle(1)\rangle$ in common.