# Want an example of two sylow-p subgroups whose intersection was not trivial $\{1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I'm having some confusion in a proof.

Suppose $G$ was a group of order $p^\alpha*m$, and $n_p>1$.

Could you give me an example such that the intersection of two sylow $p$ subgroups, namely $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$, such that $P\cap gPg^{-1}\neq \{1\}$?

Or disprove it.

Comment: The Sylow 2-groups in $S_5$ are an example. As a general comment, you must have $\alpha >1$, since the intersection of two subgroups is a group, and Lagrange's theorem says this would have to divide $p$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to see it easily without computing it out as there was $15$ sylow 2 subgroup to the answer $|S_5|=120$ yet $(8-1)*15+1=106<120$. However, I found a different solution and some answers. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831424/is-the-intersection-of-distinct-conjugations-of-sylow-subgroups-trivial  But thanks anyway. By the way, was there a reason you specifically chose $S_5$? I saw something say $S_5$ was the least nonSolvable symmetric group. I haven't' learned that yet. Was that the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G$ with $|Syl_p G|\geq 2$. Now take $C_p\times G$

Comment: Thanks $C_p\times \{1\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, at least (and exactly if they were trivial intersecting)

Answer (score 2):

There are three Sylow-2 subgroups of $S_4$, each having 8 elements, each isomorphic to the dihedral group – and each containing $\{\,1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\,\}$.